# When was it publicly revealed that a KH-11 spy satellite took pictures of the first Shuttle flight?

Tags: space-shuttle, spaceflight-firsts, reconnaissance-satellite

Even before the first Shuttle flight, NASA was already concerned about possible damage during liftoff.  They had arranged for a KH-11 spy satellite to photograph the shuttle in orbit.  The operation was kept secret:

> Young and Crippen were instructed to perform maneuvers with the RCS thrusters to align *Columbia* so that the KH-11 could photograph it, but were not informed of the reason for them.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-1

The pictures were analyzed while the shuttle was still in orbit, and the damage was considered acceptable enough for *Columbia* to land normally.

Because we know of these events today, the operation was revealed to the public at some point.  Who and when revealed this operation?

(Coincidentally, the size of the shuttle's payload bay was designed to ferry spy satellites to and from orbit.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This was revealed in [2015](http://www.thespacereview.com/article/3219/1), in the book Into the Black, about STS-1.

> The hardcover edition of Into the Black had the overall basics of the imaging effort, although not specific details. ... His new version of the story in the paperback edition indicates that the imaging attempt had been planned starting over a year before the flight.

That revised paperback edition was published in [April, 2017](https://www.airspacemag.com/daily-planet/spysat-and-shuttle-180962872/):

> The first flight of the space shuttle, 36 years ago today, .... Until now, few people knew the details of a secret effort to inspect Columbia during its two days in orbit using the KH-11 spy satellite. Writer Rowland White tells the story in this condensed excerpt from the new, revised edition of his history of STS-1, Into The Black, to be published by Touchstone on April 18.

The crew did know they were being observed by a spy satellite, but this was not discussed on open comms:

> Among the handful of people at JSC briefed on the NRO’s involvement were the primary and backup shuttle crews, who were already training for the first flight. Invited into the vault, the four astronauts listened intently as The Plan was described in detail. After considering what was said, Columbia’s STS-1 Commander, John Young, asked: “Well, what do we have to do in all this?”
>
> "Nothing really,” replied Ken Young, ‘Just perform the maneuvers and orientations we send up. And don’t ask anything on the open loop if some attitude change seems weird or unconventional.”

...

> while NASA’s press kit explained that each day the “launch windows opened at local sunrise plus 45 minutes and are more than 6 hours in duration,” Lineberry and Young knew that, while in theory that was right, in practice there was almost no flexibility at all. The two of them had chosen the launch time of 0700 hours EST very specifically. It was when they had determined that the shuttle would have to launch in order to optimize the opportunities for the NRO to capture images of Columbia in orbit.

Comment: I've removed my part of the question about the astronauts knowing, but left the Wikipedia quote as is.

Comment: Looks like I'm gonna have to get that book.  There are a bunch of used copies available though, not sure that is a good sign.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I enjoyed it, though I obviously could have overlooked many sins you would notice. :)

Comment: After reading the book I did a little searching of KH-11 and was little depressed for few days after learning that while civilian astronomers have struggled three decades with a single Hubble Space Telescope, military has operated a vast fleet of almost identical satellites - pointing downwards. As a humanity, we really have our eggs in wrong basket.

Comment: I've often wondered if such a capability would have help us out when STS-107 was in orbit...

Comment: @Digger there were several attempts including at least one by Wayne Hale to image the vehicle using DOD assets. But Space Shuttle Program management stopped them.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I'm about half way through the book and really liking it. I especially appreciate how it emphasizes the role of the SMS in problem resolution and procedure development.  So far I've only found one minor error.

Comment: @OrganicMarble:  "SMS" - are you referring to the 70's era weather satellite program?

Comment: Shuttle Mission Simulator.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've read the book, and can wholeheartedly recommend it. The KH-11 imaging is just one part of the story it tells.

Comment: @Hobbes thanks! I enjoyed it too.