# Why did the KH-11 get the nickname "Kennen"?

Tags: reconnaissance-satellite

The KH-11 has been one of the United States' most important models of spy satellites, and much of its design is similar to the Hubble Space Telescope.  "KH" is an abbreviation for [Key Hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_Hole).

The KH-11 model is also known as "[Kennen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KH-11_Kennen)".  **How did the satellite get this name?**

---

Related:

- [When was it publicly revealed that a KH-11 spy satellite took pictures of the first Shuttle flight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35993/26446)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the National Reconnaissance Office [website](https://www.nro.gov/Portals/65/documents/foia/declass/ForAll/033017/F-2017-00026.pdf):

[image: Some time ago Dr. Naka stated the desire to select the Codeword for the EOI system upon the retirement of the ZAMAN nom-de-plume. He announced at staff meeting on November 23 that KENNEN had been selected. The term is Middle English, and means "to perceive." (common usage now is "ken.")]

Comment: I have never seen such a clear to the point answer to such an obscure question :D

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that the word ["kennen"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kennen) exists in German and Dutch as a verb meaning "to know".

Comment: We could remove question-answering privileges from everyone except @OrganicMarble and nobody would notice, since s/he ends up answering everything anyway :p

Comment: @IanKemp lol, but a lot of stuff here is out of my wheelhouse: orbital mechanics, planetary science, (really science in general), Soviet space, anything that involves electromagnetism, etc, etc.

Comment: To expand on what @Gallifreyan is saying: German actually has two different words for "to know": "kennen", which more subtly means "to be familiar with" and is generally used in reference to people, i.e., "to know s.o.", and "wissen", which means "to know as a fact"